# String.ValueOf() to replace NULL with string null when calling a method

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to use `String.valueOf()` to replace the null when i'm calling some method.But it still shows `nullpointerexception`. This may be simple but i'm missing something.

I have statement like this

```
myvar = this.kind.name().toLowerCase()
```

It is throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Im trying to keep string "NULL" whenever i get NPE. so i tried this

```
myvar = String.valueOf(this.kind.name().toLowerCase()) -- not working
```

I have found from other posts that it may not work as we have overloaded method `String.valueOf(char[])` and `String.valueOf(object)` and suggested to use below. But still it s not working. How do i assign string `null` in this case?

```
myvar = String.valueOf((this.kind.name().toLowerCase()) null))
```

Comment: @joe , I'm not asking what is `nullpointerexception`. Please read the question.

Comment: Show the NPE trace. I expect name()  (which should be getName()?) to return NULL.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `this.kind` that is null?

Comment: Could be, that's why I ask for stack trace.

Comment: @rsp, even i'm not sure. How to handle if that is the case?

Comment: @Crazy2crack If `this.kind` is null, you should be able to determine that from the stacktrace. You can handle the situation by adding an if-condition or code like `String.valueOf(this.kind == null ? null : this.kind.name()).toLowercase()`.

Comment: @rsp. Yes `this.kind` is null. It worked. Can you please post this as answer. I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `this.kind` is null, you should be able to determine that from the stacktrace.

You can handle the situation by adding an if-condition or code like

```
String.valueOf(this.kind == null ? null : this.kind.name()).toLowercase()
```

Answer (score 10):

You should be using

```
myvar = String.valueOf(this.kind.name()).toLowerCase();
```

not

```
myvar = String.valueOf(this.kind.name().toLowerCase());
```

As documentation of `valueOf()` describes

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned

So,`String.valueOf(this.kind.name())` would return `"null"`

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, it is still throwing the NPE :(

Comment: Debug your code and check what does `String.valueOf(this.kind.name())` returns

Comment: @Crazy2crack: So add stack trace to see, who's throwing the exception